# How to download the file that this file is created in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, download

My webapplication : I click a button, this button call a web service function, this function create a file(using DocX dll). I want to download this file just created via web browser similar download a file on web.
How to do it?

My code below

// Click button event

```
$(frm_id+' #btn_eprt_tml')
.button()
.click(function(){
            //eprt_tml
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JqueryFunction.aspx/eprt_tml",
                data: "{ptcn_id:'"+ptcn_id+"'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    alert("Completed");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Not completed");
                }
            });
```

//eprt_tml function

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void eprt_tml(int ptcn_id)
{
    DocX g_document;   
    try
    {
        // Store a global reference to the loaded document.
        g_document = DocX.Load(@"D:\Project\CRM1\tml\tml_tpt.docx");
        g_document = crt_from_tpl(DocX.Load(@"D:\Project\CRM1\tml\tml_tpt.docx"));
        // Save all changes made to this template as Invoice_The_Happy_Builder.docx (We don't want to replace InvoiceTemplate.docx).
        //g_document.Save();
        g_document.SaveAs(@"D:\Project\CRM1\tml\Invoice_The_Happy_Builder.docx");
    }
        // The template 'Template.docx' does not exist, so create it.
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {

    }
}
```

//crt_from_tpl function

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    private static DocX crt_from_tpl(DocX template)
    {
        template.AddCustomProperty(new CustomProperty("static_title", "afdaslfjlk"));
        template.AddCustomProperty(new CustomProperty("tmlname", "asdfasdfasf"));
        template.AddCustomProperty(new CustomProperty("tmlcontent", "asdfasd"));
        template.AddCustomProperty(new CustomProperty("ptcnname", "asdasdfsd"));
        template.AddCustomProperty(new CustomProperty("ptcntitle", "asdfasdfsad"));
        template.AddCustomProperty(new CustomProperty("coursename", "asdfsadsdf"));
        return template;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the file name on the basis of SessionID

Replace ur "tml_tpt" to "HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID"

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public static void eprt_tml(int ptcn_id)
{
    DocX g_document;   
    try
    {
        // Store a global reference to the loaded document.
        g_document = DocX.Load(@"D:\Project\CRM1\tml\tml_tpt.docx");
        g_document = crt_from_tpl(DocX.Load(@"D:\Project\CRM1\tml\tml_tpt.docx"));
        // Save all changes made to this template as Invoice_The_Happy_Builder.docx (We don't want to replace InvoiceTemplate.docx).
        //g_document.Save();
        g_document.SaveAs(@"D:\Project\CRM1\tml\Invoice_The_Happy_Builder.docx");
    }
        // The template 'Template.docx' does not exist, so create it.
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain more. I'm beginer. Thanks you